# rostwitter consumer key

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear Ros users,
I'm trying to user the hydro-rostwitter package (get using sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-rostwitter), but when running get_access_token.py, it asks me a consumer key (not a twitter login).

But I wouldn't like to develop my own twitter app, I just would like to post a tweet from a rostopic :)
Thank you for your support!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194051/rostwitter-consumer-key/) by [Rahndall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3415/rahndall/) on ROS Answers with karma: 133 on 2014-10-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The rostwitter package use the python-twitter API (and for twitter this is considered as an app!). You have to make your personal registration to the twitter application manager to get all the security keys to put in the yaml configuration file. You have no choice ;-)

---

Originally posted by [rastaxe](https://answers.ros.org/users/2870/rastaxe/) with karma: 620 on 2014-10-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have rewrite rostwitter package and released as 1.0.45, this version should work only with deb dependency, please try them once it is available on repository.

https://github.com/jsk-ros-pkg/jsk_common/pull/549

---

Originally posted by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) with karma: 1186 on 2014-10-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1